# UE5 Errors - "incomplete type is not allowed"

Tags: unreal-engine5

I created mobile platform project in Unreal Engine 5, made some coding, it is compiling and works fine. But there is a problem with some errors that do not interfere with compilation and I did not even touch this, so what does it mean and how to fix it?
[image: Errors]

Comment: Is it possible you’re using unity builds? They can cause invalid code (missing includes in source files) to build. Alternatively, it might just be that the errors list is reporting false errors, epic warn about that in the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/VisualStudioSetup/).